# making one of two div invisible based on condition in jsp using jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

A jsp page recieves an enum variable that can have four values

```
public enum userType
{
    manager,HOD,consultant,support;
}
```

The jsp page has two divs, the first div should only be visible if the enum variable is **support** . 
The second div should always be visible regardless of usertype.
this is what I have done and I get a screen without output.

```
<c:if test= "${(usertype.toString().equals(support)) == false}">
        <div id ="supportOnly" style = "display:none">
            <form action ="newquery.jsp" method="post">
                <%
                   //the userID variable is sent to the next page
                    session.setAttribute("userID", userID);
                %>
                 <input type="submit" value="New Query">
            </form>
        </div>
    </c:if>

    <%--
        the form below is used to search for a query
        all users may search for queries  
    --%>
    <c:if test ="${(usertype.toString().equals(support)) || (usertype.toString().equals(consultant))|| (usertype.toString().equals(HOD)) || (usertype.toString().equals(Manager))}">
        <div id ="allUsers">
            <form action ="searchquery.jsp" method="post"> 
                <%
                    //the userID variable is sent to the next page
                    session.setAttribute("userID", userID);
                %>
                <input type="submit" value="View Query">
            </form> 
        </div>
    </c:if>
```

Comment: you could try `<c:if test= "${usertype eq 'support' >` instead `<c:if test= "${(usertype.toString().equals(support)) == false}">`

Comment: Thank you. It seemed as though my variables were not being properly due to the scopes in which they were being created . I used 
pageContext.setAttribute("SuserType", SuserType);